# Steps to follow for deploying my vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, deployment, installation, setup-deployment

I am ready to deploy my vb.net project to my client computer.

In my development computer I have crystal report 9, sql server express and .net framework 3.5 installed.

My Client computer hasn't got anything installed there...

I am trying to making msi installer so that it will be easy for my client to install.

I created the new solutions -> setup type project, added the project on it and build it.

it successfully created the msi installer but it doesn't installs the sql server express and crystal report.

How do i make the installer with crystal report and sql server and also with db

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Visual Studio you are using but assuming you have 2008:

To add the crystal reports files to the setup project:

1. Go to the deployment project's properties page.
2. Click the "Prerequisites" button.
3. Add the "Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008"

Alternatively search for the correct Merge Modules for your Crystal Reports version.

I am yet to see an 'easy' install that includes Crystal Reports but you never know.

You'll have to deploy the database seperately, just install SQL Server Express and do a backup-restore on the database.

Comment: In the prerequisites box you can also check "SQL Server 2005 Express Edition" (that's what I get in my VS 2008 SP1)